# Android TV box like Sunvell T95Z

Tags: android

I'm looking for an Android TV box recommendation.
I found this one: [TV Box Sunvell T95Z Plus](http://www.gearbest.com/tv-box-mini-pc/pp_443590.html) but the last review I saw was from January and I don't know if there is anything better than Sunvell T95Z Plus.

The characteristics of the TV box would be pretty much what this one has: **Android+HDMI+WIFI**

Thank you all in advance!